# I am trying to extract the word and correlation from findAssoc in R

Tags: r, matrix, correlation, cpu-word, tm

I have been scouring the internet for a solution and thought I found one, but I think upgrades to the tm package have changed the output to findAssoc.

I have built both the term document matrix and the document term matrix from a corpus.  When I run the following I get a list or words with the correlations.

```
serviceAssoc <- findAssocs(serviceTDM, "service", 0.10)
```

The output looks like the following:

```
customer     desk  ...
    0.63     0.25
```

This gives a nice list (list of 1) of words paired with their correlation.

Is there any way to split the word and correlation to put this in a matrix or data frame for plotting?  In a past post, the following code was shown to work, but R now gives a dimensional error.

```
servicedf <- data.frame(
                    corr = findAssocs(serviceTDM, "service",.10)[,1],
                    terms = row.names(findAssocs(serviceTDM,"service",.10)))
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
corr = c(0.63,0.25)
names(corr) = c("customer", "desk")
corr

customer     desk 
    0.63     0.25 

servicedf <- data.frame(corr = as.vector(corr), terms = names(corr))
servicedf
```

Output:

```
  corr    terms
1 0.63 customer
2 0.25     desk
```

Then you can slice n dice the resulting dataframe

Comment: The customer and desk with the correlations under them as they appear above are the output of `serviceAssoc <- findAssocs(serviceTDM, "service", 0.10)` but they are not separate vectors.  The output is comprised of 77 words and their paired correlations and the goal is to split them.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer.  First perform the following:

```
serviceAssoc <- findAssocs(serviceTDM, "service", 0.10)
```

Unlist it: `data <- unlist(serviceAssoc)`

To get the values use `as.numeric(data)` and then use the `names(data)` to get the words and assign them to separate vectors, combine and plot.